# How to use MutationObserver to update handling of DOMNodeInserted event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mutation-observers

I have code like so:

```
function load_ui_globals() {
    $('legend').addClass('ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
}

$(function(){
    load_ui_globals();
    $('#main').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {load_ui_globals();});
});
```

It throws a message of:

> Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.

In trying to update the code I came up with this (but it is not working):

```
function load_ui_globals() {
    $('legend').addClass('ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
}

$(function(){
    load_ui_globals();

    var callback = function(mutationsList) {
        for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
                console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                load_ui_globals();
            }
        }
    };
    var targetNode = document.getElementById('main');
    var config = { childList: true };
    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
});
```

The new code does not trigger the reload of `load_ui_globals()` as originally intended.  How do I use the MutationObserver correctly, while keeping original functionality?

The original code was not mine so I may not fully grasp what it was supposed to trigger, but it looks to me like it is supposed to apply `load_ui_globals()` directives to any newly-loaded node (via AJAX).

Comment: Add subtree:true to the config. There's also no need for the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks, `subtree:true` works.  But why no `for` loop?  `mutationsList` is an array.. how would you suggest not using the `for` loop?

Comment: Because there's no need for the loop. Here's the entire code you need: new MutationObserver(load_ui_globals).observe(document.getElementById('main'), {childList: true, subtree: true})